# Update product info with ajax

Tags: product, configurable-product, blocks, ajax

How can I update whole block product.info from ajax controller?

```
 public function indexAction(){
    $prod_id  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('simpleProductId');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);

    $result = array(
        "sku" =>$product->getData('sku'),
        "name" => $product->getName(),
        "shortDescr" => "desc",
        "delivery" => "delivery",
        "price" => "price"
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

For now, I'm updating single parts of it, but how update whole block?

Comment: echo the whole product info block in your controller and update the same on the product view page.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
 <?php
    class[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_[ControllerName] extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

         public function indexAction(){

            if ($product = $this->_initProduct()) {
                $result=array();
                Mage::register('productId', $product->getId());

                $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
                $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($product);
                if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                    $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
                }
                $this->_initProductLayout($product);

                  $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')->toHtml();
                    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

              //  $this->renderLayout();
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {

            }
        }
        /**
         * Load specific layout handles by product type id
         *
         */
        protected function _initProductLayout($product)
        {
            $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();

            $update->addHandle('default');
            $update->addHandle('catalog_product_view');
            $this->addActionLayoutHandles();


            $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$product->getTypeId());

            if ($product->getPageLayout()) {
                $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
                    ->applyHandle($product->getPageLayout());
            }

            $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
            if ($product->getPageLayout()) {
                $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
                    ->applyTemplate($product->getPageLayout());
            }
            $update->addUpdate($product->getCustomLayoutUpdate());
            $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
        }


        protected function _initProduct()
        {
            $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('simpleProductId');

            $product = $this->_loadProduct($productId);
            if (!$product) {
                return false;
            }

            if ($categoryId) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                Mage::register('current_category', $category);
            }

            try {
                Mage::dispatchEvent('customajax_controller_product_init', array('product'=>$product));
                Mage::dispatchEvent('customajax_controller_product_init_after', array(
                    'product'           => $product,
                    'controller_action' => $this
                ));
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
                return false;
            }

            return $product;
        }

        /**
         * Load product model with data by passed id.
         * Return false if product was not loaded or has incorrect status.
         *
         * @param int $productId
         * @return bool|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
         */
        protected function _loadProduct($productId)
        {
            if (!$productId) {
                return false;
            }

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog() || !$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                return false;
            }

            Mage::register('current_product', $product);
            Mage::register('product', $product);

            return $product;
        }

    }
```

In this code ,i have ***implemented the logic of  write review page***

```
[/review/product/list/id/425/#review-form]
```

means `Mage_Review_ProductController controller` 's  listAction. rendering process.

and only  return output of **product.info** (`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')->toHtml();`).

and using

```
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

**return json output**